# DataTables set complex headers from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

DataTables provide the following example to implement complex headers: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
                <th colspan="2">HR Information</th>
                <th colspan="3">Contact</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>8422</td>
                <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>1562</td>
                <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>6224</td>
                <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>5407</td>
                <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>4804</td>
                <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>9608</td>
                <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>6200</td>
                <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>2360</td>
                <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>1667</td>
                <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>3814</td>
                <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>9497</td>
                <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>6741</td>
                <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>3597</td>
                <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>1965</td>
                <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>1581</td>
                <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>3059</td>
                <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>1721</td>
                <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>2558</td>
                <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>2290</td>
                <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>1937</td>
                <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>6154</td>
                <td>y.berry@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>8330</td>
                <td>c.vance@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>3023</td>
                <td>d.wilder@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>5797</td>
                <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>8822</td>
                <td>g.joyce@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>9239</td>
                <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>1314</td>
                <td>b.wagner@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>2947</td>
                <td>f.green@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>8899</td>
                <td>s.itou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>2769</td>
                <td>m.house@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>6832</td>
                <td>s.burks@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>3606</td>
                <td>p.bartlett@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>2860</td>
                <td>g.cortez@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>8240</td>
                <td>m.mccray@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>5384</td>
                <td>u.butler@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>7031</td>
                <td>h.hatfield@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>6318</td>
                <td>h.fuentes@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>9422</td>
                <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>7580</td>
                <td>t.mooney@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>1042</td>
                <td>j.bradshaw@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>2120</td>
                <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>6222</td>
                <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>9383</td>
                <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>8327</td>
                <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>2927</td>
                <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>8352</td>
                <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>7439</td>
                <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>4389</td>
                <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>3431</td>
                <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>3990</td>
                <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>1016</td>
                <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>6733</td>
                <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>8196</td>
                <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>6373</td>
                <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>5384</td>
                <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>4226</td>
                <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

However, I am using JavaScript initialization:

```js
 var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      data: myData,
      dom: "B<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
      columns: [ {
        title: "Position",
        data: 'position'
      }, {
        title: "Salary",
        data: 'salary'
      }, {
        title: "Office",
        data: 'office'
      }, {title: "Extn",
        data: 'Extn'}, 
         {title: "Email",
        data: 'Email'}],
});
```

```html
<table id="cacheTable" class="table-striped">
</table>
```

This in itself works fine (example doesn't include data/libraries), but now how do I add the complex headers when I instantiate DataTables in this way?

Comment: here is tutorial https://youtu.be/A3-p3psej_w

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You build complex header by including `thead` element in your HTML markup, no matter what the data source is. There is no need for `columns.title` if you're using complex header.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [{"name":"Tiger Nixon","position":"System Architect","salary":"$320,800","start_date":"2011/04/25","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"5421"}];
  
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [
            { data: "name" },
            { data: "position" },
            { data: "office" },
            { data: "extn" },
            { data: "start_date" },
            { data: "salary" }
        ]        
    });
} );
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
                <th colspan="2">HR Information</th>
                <th colspan="3">Contact</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Leaving out all the titles, and defining ALL the columns in the HTML works. Not a pure JavaScript solution but it does the job.